# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function on .append function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

```
function hydrateServiceTypeDropDownList() {
        var serviceID = $get('<%=serviceIDInEdit.ClientID%>').value;
        var campaignID = $get('<%=campaignID.ClientID%>').value;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("AddEditService.aspx/BindServiceType") %>',
            data: JSON.stringify({ serviceID: serviceID, campaignID: campaignID }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                handleData(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function handleData(data) {
        var serviceTypeDropDownList = $get('<%= servicesFormView.FindControl("serviceTypeDropDownList").ClientID %>');
        $.each(data.d, function (key, item) {
            serviceTypeDropDownList.append(
                $('<option />', {
                     value: item.Value, text: item.Text
                }));
        });
    }
```

This code was working but I lost these two functions in a rollback so I had to rewrite it. Now I get this error. What am I missing? serviceTypeDropDownList, data.d, key, and item all pass the correct data.

Crome debugger stack trace:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 
(anonymous function) 
v.extend.each   
$.ajax.success 
v.Callbacks.l 
v.Callbacks.c.fireWith 
T 
v.support.ajax.v.ajaxTransport.send.r
```

Comment: From the error message you can find the error.  It would seem that `serviceTypeDropDownList` has no method called `append`

Comment: $get? is what - another method? or a typing error? or do you simply want to select an html fragment with it?

Comment: try `$(serviceTypeDropDownList).append()`

Comment: It looks like serviceTypeDropDownList is null by that I mean "var serviceTypeDropDownList = $get('<%= servicesFormView.FindControl("serviceTypeDropDownList").ClientID %>');" is not setting anything in serviceTypeDropDownList varriable.. To make sure you can use the check if (serviceTypeDropDownList != null && serviceTypeDropDownList.length > 0) { here you can write all you code to append }

Comment: user3154108 answer did the trick. I would have been looking at the code all day before figuring that out. Thanks a ton guys.

Comment: The problem was, that .append is a jQeury function. It can only be called from jQuery objects, not from pure DOM objects. $() encapsules a DOM object inside a jQuery object, giving it the .append function.

Answer (score 0):

`$get` should be `$.get`. First and second line of your hydrateServiceTypeDropDownList() function and the first line of your handleData() function.